# GeoJSON Python Eve Example

Tags: eve

I am trying to make a GeoJSON query work as per the Eve documentation (v0.6.1-dev): http://python-eve.org/features.html

However, the query in postman returns an error:

**Postman GET:** http://localhost:5000/people?where={"location": {"$near": {"$geometry": {"type":"Point", "coordinates": [10.0, 20.0]}, "$maxDistance": 1000}}}

**Error:**
500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

The 'people' collection contains the location as show below:

**Postman GET:** http://localhost:5000/people

```
"_items": [
    {
        "_updated": "Wed, 30 Sep 2015 10:26:51 GMT",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "born": "Thu, 27 Aug 1970 14:37:13 GMT",
        "role": [
            "author"
        ],
        **"location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                100,
                0
            ]
        },**
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "people/560bb8eb6adf7d0e70f26cd0",
                "title": "person"
            }
        },
```

Any idea why this does not work ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to switch on debug mode (set `DEBUG = True` in settings) and see what the actual error is. It is very likely that there is no geo index for the field (Eve does not automatically create indexes for you).

UPDATE: Starting with v0.6, you can also ask Eve to maintain the index for you, see the `mongo_indexes` keyword in the docs

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick: > db.people.ensureIndex({location:"2dsphere"});

Comment: Excellent. Starting with v0.6 you can also ask Eve to maintain the index for you, see the `mongo_indexes` keyword in the docs.